# passing as parameter the value of a component html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe is my question trivial, but I could not found a answer. Maybe I have been to much hours in front of the monitor :)
I have this situation:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style='margin-left: -50px;'>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="?c=Student&a=list" id="protokol"> List Studens</a>
</div>
```

This represent a button and with the click event, using MVC, the controller `Student` is called and the function `list` executed. But I need to send a parameter to this function that is the value of a HTML component.

```
<input type='text' id='parm' value=''>
```

How I can do this using the same structure? I tryed this, but is not correct

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style='margin-left: -50px;'>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="?c=Student&a=list&v=<script>$('param').val();</script>" id="protokol"> List Studens</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you can attach a click handler to that element which appends the current value of the `input`. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#protokol').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser going to the default URL
        var url = $(this).attr('href') + '&v=' + $('#param').val();
        window.location.assign(url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style='margin-left: -50px;'>
    <a id="targetLink" class="btn btn-primary" href="?c=Student&a=list&v=<script></script>" id="protokol"> List Studens</a>
</div>

//document ready
$(function(){
    var parameter = $('param').val();
    $('#targetLink').attr('href', '?c=Student&a=list&v=' + parameter);
});
```

Comment: Thx! godmode. Your idea was very good in general was what I wanted, but I complete with the idea of Rory McCrossan